# Navigation bar code information

Tags: css, xhtml

I have finally figured out how to do the navigation bar in CSS after many hours in difficulty. However, I don't fully understand what's going on.

For example I have the following :

```
#dog{
}

#dog ul
{
}

#dog ul li
{
 }

#dog li ul
{
}

#dog ul li a 
 {
 }

 #dog li:hover ul
{
}

#dog li:hover li
{
}
```

Obviously I information inside these but I'm just really confused with the amount of different ones we have. E.g. "ul li a", why can't we have them all In one ? could someone briefly explain what each one does ?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
#dog {
}
```

This selects elements with the id "dog"

```
#dog ul {
}
```

This selects `<ul>` elements that are in an element with the id "dog"

```
#dog ul li {
}
```

This selects `<li>` elements that are in a `<ul>` element that are in an element with the id "dog"

```
#dog li ul {
}
```

This selects `<ul>` elements that are in a `<li>` element that are in an element with the id "dog"

```
#dog ul li a {
}
```

This selects `<a>` elements that are in a `<li>` element that are in a `<ul>` element that are in an element with the id "dog"

```
#dog li:hover ul {
}
```

This selects `<ul>` elements that are in a `<li>` element while it is being hovered over that are in a `<ul>` element that are in an element with the id "dog"

```
#dog li:hover li {
}
```

This selects `<li>` elements that are in a `<li>` element that are being hovered over that are in an element with the id "dog"

Think I got everything right, but if you find this confusing, I highly recommend going back over the basics and maybe take the [codecademy course](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/css-coding-with-style/0/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
 #dog{
 }
```

Is a CSS id selector. Has highest precedence. Selects one unique lement with this id.

```
#dog ul {
```

}

Selects all children ul elements within the element with id 'dog'

```
#dog ul li {
}
```

Selects all children li elements within the element with id 'dog'

```
#dog li ul {
}
```

Selects all children ul elements with a li as parent within the element with id 'dog'
**Will also take precedence over #dog ul**

```
 #dog ul li a {
 }
```

Selects all children a elements with a li as parent within the element with id 'dog'

```
#dog li:hover ul {
```

}

Selects all children ul when  li parent element is hovered within the element with id 'dog'

```
#dog li:hover li {
}
```

Selects all children li when li parent element is hovered within the element with id 'dog'